# Zoom Image on tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

Is there a way to zoom images in different tabs at the same time. I tried to make a zoom effect  on tabs .

In [Here](http://jsbin.com/itekek/58)

And i used **getElementById** function for it. Inspite of using this i have to zoom all the images at the same time.

I tried to use **getElementsByClassName** but even its not working.

Is there a way to apply this by dynamically setting the ID to that pic tag while clicking on that tab?(Its ok in this case to zoom individually)

Here i also tried to pass ID on zoom function but its also having some errors while zoom in different tabs [BIN](http://jsbin.com/itekek/54/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to store the images in divs with different IDs. You can only have one element with the same ID per page. I would add a function to determine which tab you're on like this:

```
var currentTab = 0;
function switchTab(tabID) {
  currentTab = tabID;
  // code to load the tab's contents here
}

function zoom() {
  var img = document.getElementById("pic"+currentTab);
  // the rest of the zoom code goes here
}

<ul>
  <li onclick="switchTab(0);">Tab 1</li>
  <li onclick="switchTab(1);">Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<img id="pic0" src="firstpic.jpg" />
<img id="pic1" src="secondpic.jpg" />
```

If you do it that way each image should zoom properly, because now only the first one works. Just keep up with which image you're on and give them unique ID's and it should work fine.

Here is a link to a page that I made which demonstrates this functionality: http://mdl.fm/f/zoom.html